# Unable to fetch data from sqlite even when data is there (Mostly occuring in Android 9 devices)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a simple raw query for fetching data from sqlite but cursor is returning count 0 but when I execute same query through sqlite manager on same db, it is fetching results. It is getting replicated every time in few devices.

Here is my code

```
 public PinInfoHandler getParentForPincode(String pinCode) {
    PinInfoHandler pinInfo = null;
    Cursor cur = null;
    try{
        String query = "select STATE_ID,CITY_ID,KEY from PIN_MST where PINCODE='" + pinCode + "'";
        cur = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                pinInfo = new PinInfoHandler(cur.getString(0), cur.getString(1), pinCode, cur.getString(2));
            }
        }

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        logs.logsForError (ROOT + " Exception in method-- getParentForPincode :: " + org.apache.commons.lang.exception.ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
    }finally {
        Utility.closeCursor(cur);
    }
    return pinInfo;
}
```

[image: Here is the query from sqlite]

Answer (score 0):

Try Below:-

```
String query = "select STATE_ID,CITY_ID,KEY from PIN_MST where PINCODE = ? ";
String[] arg = {pinCode};
cur = db.rawQuery(query, arg);
```